# StreetView crashes Safari in IOS (API v3)

Tags: javascript, ios, google-street-view

It appears there's a memory problem when using full screen StreetView on IOS,
either in your own app or Google's site in Safari on retina iPad, possibly others?

In StreetView keep hitting the arrows that change position quickly and soon the app
(or Safari) will be forcibly closed due to a low memory condition.

One fix is to add a listener to the panorama and toggle visibility off and on ...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(pan, 'position_changed', function() { panmove(); });

function panmove()
{
    pan.setVisible(false);
    setTimeout(function() { pan.setVisible(true); }, 10);
}
```

Did anyone else run into this issue, and is there another solution,
as toggling the visibility causes StreetView to go blank for a short while.